# drupal google doc type module

Tags: drupal, google-docs

I am looking to create a Google Doc type environment in Drupal. The ability for registered users of a website to add a new document, add rows that correspond with columns, and be able to add color styling to the fields, and formatting to text. The different docs will be able to be created by different users, but do not have the ability to create new content types.
Is this the way to go? 
https://drupal.org/project/ckeditor-googledoc

Joshi,
I have downloaded the Sheetnode module, installed...

downloaded the socialcalc masterfile, unzipped, and placed it in the sheetnode folder

[image]

then turned all

[image]

and I still can't get my spreadsheet to show up when creating new content...

[image]

thanks for any help you can give...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try any or all of the following modules:
https://drupal.org/project/ajax_document_viewer
https://drupal.org/project/gdoc_field
or https://drupal.org/project/sheetnode

Regards.